# Using Vue Material UI Components with Bootstrap Layout

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

I am starting my first Vue 2 project and would like to mix Vue Material Components with Bootstrap layout. I have enough experience with Angular Material components to know that mixing them with Bootstrap causes problems. I would like to use Vue Material and integrate it with a Bootstrap theme template. Is this going to be a problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, you can install the material and the bootstrap without a problem, just be careful when calling the styles, because whoever is last